# BeginForm() with different routeValue depending on the item clicked

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I'm using an IEnumerable to list all `Groups` in my database. I have group `Contacts` that are listed after each group. I want to have a modal that appears when the "Add Group Contact" button is clicked, which will allow users to select a contact to add.

The problem is that I'm passing in a `routeValue` attribute that needs to be changed depending on which group's "Add Group Contact" button has been clicked. I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactManager.Models.Groups>
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    ...
    <span style="font-size:120%"><b>Group Contacts</b></span>
    <span><a id="addBtn" href="javascript:addContact(@item.Group.GroupId);">Add Group Contact</a></span>
    ...
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Groups", routeValues: new { id = placeholder }, method: FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        ...
    </div>
}


<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    function addContact(id){
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Research yields not much, but I have tried putting the modal code within the `foreach` statement and doing `routeValues: new { id = @item.Group.GroupId }` directly which doesn't work of course, but is what I want to do.

Comment: In your `addContact()` function, you can just update the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element.

Comment: Sounds like this should be done in `addContact` function: `$('form').attr('action', '[action URL]')`. Use `form` selector if the form doesn't have any ID bound to it.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you both for the comments. This would be my first time getting into JQuery! I'll try it out.

Comment: Perfect. Works great, thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  you can put the id for the form and set action attribute in the javascript like below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Groups", routeValues: new { id = placeholder }, method: FormMethod.Post ,  , new { @id = "frm1" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        ...
    </div>
}
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    function addContact(id){
        modal.style.display = "block";
    $('#frm1').attr('action', '../groups/delete?id=id')

    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Karthik